# How to render partial index in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

On my dashboard I'm trying to render a partial as a table (index)

My partial: _transaction.html.erb
That partial is actually an index, based on transactions index. It should return all transactions in a table. My partial contains:

```
  <% @transactions.each do |transaction| %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= transaction.transaction_type %></td>
    <td><%= transaction.date %></td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
```

The error I receive:

"You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each"

Comment: It seems you don't have the @transactions variable set at all. Are you sure you're setting it on the controller? Maybe forgot a @ before it's name?

Answer (score 2):

That would seem to indicate that your `TransactionsController#index` action is not returning anything for @transactions. **The most obvious cause is that whatever logic you are using to find records is broken, returning 0 results, or not setting @transactions correctly.**

In views like that, you want to do an error check for the situation where you have no results (or an error of some sort).

Your index.html view:

```
<% if !@transactions || @transactions.length == 0 %>
    <p>'No transactions found.'</p>
<% else %>
    <table>
        <!-- put your column headers here -->
        <!-- the next line iterates through each transaction and calls a "_transaction" partial to render the content -->
        <%= render @transactions %>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

Your _transaction.html.erb partial:

```
<tr>
    <td><%= transaction.transaction_type %></td>
    <td><%= transaction.date %></td>
</tr>
```

That will get your view working again. The next step is to figure out why your controller action is not returning results. Start by opening a rails console and trying to retrieve records:

```
>> Transaction.all
```

If that returns any results, then you have data. If not, create a record either via a web interface you've developed or via the rails console:

```
>> t = Transaction.new()
>> t.transaction_type = 1 #or whatever is appropriate for your application
>> t.date = Date.today
>> t.valid? #if true, your record will save. If not, you need to fix the fields so they validate
>> t.save
```

Once you have a record, test your view again. If it still fails, you probably have an error in your controller logic. As to what that error could be, you'll need to post it for us to help you with that. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Shaun. Works like a charm. How would I update my views to display transactions through a scope?

Comment: Your controller actions should be referencing the scopes on your model to get the information and place it into your @transactions variable. From there, your views will just refer to @transactions as the collection of data from that particular scope.

Comment: Also, you may want to do a favor for all the people who have answered your questions and go back and accept them by clicking on the check mark below the vote score if the answer was the one you needed. Not only will that help other people who have the same question in the future, but both you and the person who answered the question get a little bit of karma as well. :)